# How Do I Capture Duplicate Column Record using 1 Column with 2 Different Results

Tags: obiee

I'm a novice creating OBIEE analysis.  I searched this site looking for an answer and can't find the exact one I need.

Is there a way to capture unique `ID`s from one column that have two different results in another column?

How do I capture the Employee `ID`s that have two different ticket numbers?

```
ID    Ticket    Result
123     201     Hired
123     301     Retired
456     201     Hired
789     317     Resigned
888     210     Temp Hire
777     249     Seasonal Hire
666     209     Hired PT
666     310     Removed
456     339     Death
```

Expected results:

```
123
666
456
```

Comment: Where do you want to do that? In an analysis or in the RPD?

Comment: In the analysis.  I don't have access to the RPD (if that makes a difference).